# Export PostgreSQL data to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, postgresql

Hello I fell parachute on a project that will use MongoDB and do the import of a base using PostgreSQL, this base possess several banks and has a total of 251 tables my questions are:

1 - From what I've studied so far in MongoDB relationships I have but only one document that brings all the information I need, ie in a product table where I have the vendor id and category id to export to mongo I would have to create a document with the product + vendor information + category information, correct?

2 - Is there any program that exports these data to the mongo and generates the document with all the information I need?

Comment: It all depends how your Postgres data could map to a Mongo data model. There are also multiple ways of storing data in Mongo, embeded sub-documents or linked documents, it not that straight forward.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to take a look at the tour (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the help pages http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . This is likely to be put on hold as too broad / unclear what you're asking / off topic (software-recommendation) in its current form.